# Add image to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database, image

I'm fairly new to how sql works and I am learning. I'm working on an assignment where we have to search for movies on a database. I have the database search working but I am unsure how to load images onto my sql database. I looked online and most examples used 'bulk' but it does not work for me, I asked my professor and he said that I had to use a textbox but I do not fully understand it. An explanation or example could help.I'll attach a screenshot of my sql table that I'm working with. Am i able to add the image using query commands? or would I have to do it in asp?
[Database code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iil0.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izuQc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your table and it seams, you have a *ImageLocation* field.
Wouldn't it mean, you are supposed to store the path to your image file?
Than your *ImageLocation* field in Database would be simple `string` not an `Image`
as in it's location on the server:

```
images/PulpFiction.png
```

You could use this path to display images in your views

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImageLocation)" alt="Image" />
```

Though i am not sure if this is what you are required.

Comment: Yeah ImageLocation seems confusing, but it's meant to be the image. So i would change 'Image' to varchar? If so would i have to do anything in asp side to get the image? Or if i were to search for a movie it would already display with the result?

Comment: Yes, you would change image to `varchar`. I believe that you do not require any particular steps in ASP, because it will return as string with the rest of fields from the particular movie row you have acquired. This method should take the _ImageLocation_ string and find the file it leads to and display it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a very good reason for putting your images in a database, it is considered an anti-pattern or just bad design. You save the images to disk and store the information about the image including the (relative) path in the database. This will keep your database light and responsive and you can manage your images relatively easy. Looking at your datatable example, the field says imageLocation (not image) however you use datatype image (does that even exist ?) maybe change that to varchar(255)

Comment: Yeah i realize ImageLocation sounds confusing but it's supposed to be where the image goes